# Occupy the remaining space in terminal

Tags: terminal, linux-ubuntu

When I open the vim in the xterm (ubuntu) there's always a space on the right and bottom part of terminal which is not fully occupied by the vim. What could be the reason behind it? And what are the solutions for this problem?

*Those violet area on the right and bottom of the vim are the area from the terminal.*

[image]

Comment: I dont experience this on ubuntu 18.04 with the default terminal (gnome?), inside of tmux or out. Can you provide more details?

Comment: How does it look like if you start another program that uses the entire terminal? Like `mc` (Midnight Commander) or `htop`.

Comment: @D.BenKnoble yes it is gnome. No, I'm not using tmux or any other just right inside the terminal. @Ralf I tried `htop` but there's no problem with it only with the vim.

Comment: What Ubuntu version?

Comment: @D.BenKnoble 18.04.

Comment: No idea. Does it look the same with `vim -u NONE -U NONE`?

Answer (score 1):

That is the default behaviour. The reason is, Vim can only show complete character cells, however if your terminal is slightly bigger that what can be displayed by multiples of character cells, it will show such a frame.

There is nothing you can do about it, but you can slightly resize your terminal.